# Usage of the words: "pivotal" and "paramount"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, usage

Can the words "pivotal" and "paramount" be used with the word "advantage"?

- The most ***pivotal*** *advantage* of remote learning is...
- The most ***paramount*** *advantage* of remote learning is...

I know that probably other words can be more suitable, but...

Does it sound too awkward or quite normal?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: in "The most paramount" the word 'most' is poor usage, as 'paramount' cannot be qualified in that way. (Either something is paramount or it is not, you cannot have one thing that is 'more paramount' than another 'less paramount' thing.)

Otherwise, both 'pivotal' and 'paramount' are fine in this case.

Comment: can *pivotal* be qualified in that way, though? most/less pivotal doesn't sound right either...

Comment: interestingly, [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less+pivotal%2Cmost+pivotal%2Cmost+paramount%2C+less+paramount&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cless%20pivotal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20pivotal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20paramount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20paramount%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cless%20pivotal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20pivotal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20paramount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20paramount%3B%2Cc0) shows there are sound examples of all the four phrases ...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  It's never too hard to find examples of obvious miss-spelling's, as well as bad grammar. I didn't mention 'pivotal' as I thought it was a bit more controversial, but "Paramount" is very similar to "Ultimate", and while that word is massively misused (particularly in advertising) neither _should legitimately_ be qualified in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this link from [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paramount%20advantage%2C%20pivotal%20advantage&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparamount%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpivotal%20advantage%3B%2Cc0) you will see that your phrases ***paramount advantage*** and ***pivotal advantage*** are not very frequent. At least not as frequent as expressions like

> ***a pivotal role*** or  ***of paramount importance***

(You can find more examples at [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/paramount.html))

With ***advantage***, you could choose one of the adjectives suggested by [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20most%20%2A%20advantage&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthe%20most%20%2A%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20important%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20decided%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20essential%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20solid%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20obvious%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20signal%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20significant%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20striking%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20decisive%20advantage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20most%20marked%20advantage%3B%2Cc0), among which I think ***decisive*** or ***essential*** seem to be the closest to what you need.

However, just because Gngram finds rare instances of an expression does not mean you cannot use it. I actually found quite a few examples on Google, among which:

> But ultimately, ***the most pivotal advantage*** came in the form of a
> clearer, more utility-focused view of customers that helps accelerate
> sales cycles and improve service. (from [digitalistmag.com](https://www.digitalistmag.com/customer-experience/2018/05/07/how-digital-foundation-flips-switch-on-utilities-customer-relationships-06164546/)).

I also found quite a few results with ***the most paramount advantage***:

> ***The most paramount advantage*** to the use of transporters like PEPT1 and SMVT is the potential for increased oral absorption. (from an article on the [ncbi.nlm.nih.gov site](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2802226/))